# Efficient process SQL Server and numerical methods library

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, matlab, communication, lapack

Is there a way to comunicate a numeric method library, that can exploit all `.net's` (`numerical methods` called by `.net` that does `SQL Server` things) habilities?,

- What library do you recomend,
  maybe using `MATLAB`, `R`?
- How to comunicate `SQL Server` and `.net`  with such library or libraries?
- Do you have an example?
- What steps must be followed to make the link between `numerical libraries`, `.net` and `SQL Server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to use Matlab as a numerical library, but drive data access and control execution from c# I would recommend the following approach.

Use the COM Automation Server in Matlab by adding a reference to the `MATLAB Application Type Library (Matlab.Application)` COM object in the add reference dialog in Visual Studio.

Call your Matlab scripts from c#, see the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f135590.html#f135616) for an example.

Fetch data from the SQL Server using ADO.NET, [Linq2Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) or Entity Framework and feed that into Matlab through the COM-object created above. When the calculations are completed read out the data and store the result in the database again.

To process things in the background you can use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) in c#.

Comment: Yes in fact following your example... I would like to paralelize some things, for example: `c#` reads `SQL Server` database, then `c#`calls `MATLAB` using threads (each thread uses `MATLAB`'s habilities to compute something) then after the termination of each thread `c#` does something like store the result in `SQL Server` again, Do you have some sample code?

Comment: No, I have not used Matlab since university, but there seems to be a bunch of simple examples of how to get started on the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bq7_ykd-1.html#bra567n-1). I assume you know how to perform your numerical calculations in Matlab. I updated the answer with links to LINQ2SQL and BackgroundWorker.

Comment: I have used `MATLAB` and `SQL Server's Stored procedures`, but not to much `c#` and VB `.net` could you please post some `c#`  sample code?. So the idea is clearer (I am reading the BackgroundWorker...).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [CLR function,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136%28SQL.90%29.aspx) it has access to all (I think) .net maths libraries.

This should include 3rd party libraries too if they have a .net component